# How to reformat dataframe, suppress exponential

Tags: python, pandas

How to reformat a pandas dataframe such that there are no scientific notation such as exponential signs? And also, `serial_num` should be integer.

I tried  `df = pd.read_csv(StringIO('data.csv'))` but it didnt work.

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
print df

    id   serial_num    membershipid    date 
0   1   ["374740"]   8.6948585e+7    2016-05-06 
1   2   ["277474"]   5.2444556e+7    2016-05-06 
2   3   ["394005"]   8.5948585e+7    2016-05-06 

#Output should be this instead;

   id    serial_num  membershipid    date   
0   1     374740     86948585        2016-05-06 
1   2     277474     52444556          2016-05-06 
2   3     394005     85948585       2016-05-06
```

Comment: What does your CSV look like that is causing the `serial_num` to be a list of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
df.membershipid = df.membershipid.astype(int)
df.serial_num = df.serial_num.str.extract(r'"(.*)"', expand=False).astype(int)
```

[image]